# how to copy struct contents to another array struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

I have this c++ struct

```
struct PACKET
{
    BOOL isTCPPacket;
    BOOL isUDPPacket;
    BOOL isICMPPacket;
    BOOL isIGMPPacket;
    BOOL isARPPacket;
    BOOL isIPPacket;

    struct PETHER_HEADER
    {
        string  DestinationHost;
        string  SourceHost;
        struct PROTOCOL_TYPE
        {
            string  Name;
            WORD    Identifier;
        } ProtocolType;
    } EthernetHeader;
};
```

and i have

```
PACKET* Packet;
PACKET* Packets[6];
```

how can i copy contents of Packet into Packets[3] for example, knowing that the Packet contents will vary for each array in Packets[INDEX]

I have tried memcpy as

```
memcpy((void*)&Packets[i],(void*)&Packet,sizeof(PACKET));
```

with no luck

Comment: What do you want to copy? The actual object content or the *pointer*? Your `memcpy` is a mixture of both … Furthermore, this code reads like plain C. You’d do this very differently in C++.

Comment: There, I reverted this for you.

Answer (score 5):

How about `Packets[3] = Packet;`? This does exactly what you asked (copies the content of `Packet`, which is a pointer, into `Packets[3]`).

If you want to copy the values, you can use assignment as well: `*(Packets[3]) = *Packet;`, assuming the pointers are valid. The compiler generated assignment operator for `PACKET` should work just fine.

I'd avoid `memcpy` in this case, since some of the members are `std::string` - you're bound to run into trouble.

Comment: was kind of confused about his question, I think he ment the same thing as you said as well.

Comment: Should be `= *Packet` given his declarations, fwiw

Comment: I find it a bit of a stretch to assume that `string` refers to `std::string` here since the rest of the code is just plain C code, or alternatively very bad C++ code. But well, this answer is good nonetheless.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore when i tried *(Packets[i]) = *Packet;
the compiler said error C2100: illegal indirection

Comment: @AnwarMohamed You edited the question so the code no longer works? And expect help? `*(Packets[3]) = *Packet;` is valid if `Packet` is declared as a pointer, which it originally was. And then you edited so that it's no longer a pointer, and you ask what the problem is?

Comment: @AnwarMohamed well then, change it to `*(Packets[i]) = Packet;`. Next time - copy/paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope Packet contains valid object.
Also Packets[i] point to allocated objects.

Do this:
Packet[i] = Packet;

As string objects store pointers in their objects and can only be duplicated using assignment operator.

Comment: For assignment it’s irrelevant whether the pointers are valid, and it’s also irrelevant that the pointees contain strings.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Just one thing:

```
PACKET* Packets[6];
```

is different than:

```
PACKET (*Packets)[6];
```

Former is an array of pointer (i.e. 6-pointers), but latter is a pointer to hold address-of a `PACKET[6]` array!

In either case, you must allocate memory for your `Packet` variable. `memcpy` or assignment will not work, unless some heap or stack memory is allocated.